# Android app crashes - Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, maven, runtimeexception

need your help!

I am new in Android and for some reason my app stopped working and crashes right on startup.

I am not sure if it is related but I've added maven to the project.
Here's the error log:

```
06-23 14:32:18.380: E/AndroidRuntime(1775): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-23 14:32:18.380: E/AndroidRuntime(1775): Process: com.app.test, PID: 1775
06-23 14:32:18.380: E/AndroidRuntime(1775): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.app.test/com.test.activities.SplashActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.test.activities.SplashActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.app.test-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
06-23 14:32:18.380: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
06-23 14:32:18.380: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
06-23 14:32:18.380: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
06-23 14:32:18.380: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
06-23 14:32:18.380: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-23 14:32:18.380: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
06-23 14:32:18.380: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
06-23 14:32:18.380: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-23 14:32:18.380: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
06-23 14:32:18.380: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
06-23 14:32:18.380: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
06-23 14:32:18.380: E/AndroidRuntime(1775): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.test.activities.SplashActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.app.test-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
06-23 14:32:18.380: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
06-23 14:32:18.380: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
06-23 14:32:18.380: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
06-23 14:32:18.380: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
06-23 14:32:18.380: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
06-23 14:32:18.380: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     ... 10 more
06-23 14:32:18.380: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.activities.SplashActivity
06-23 14:32:18.380: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
06-23 14:32:18.380: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
06-23 14:32:18.380: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
06-23 14:32:18.380: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
06-23 14:32:18.380: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):         ... 13 more
06-23 14:32:18.380: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

here's the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
    <uses-permission 
        android:name = "android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name = "android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.test.activities.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.test.activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.test.activities.MainMenuActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_menu" >
        </activity>
    </application>
```

and here's the activity:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        Thread StartTimer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    sleep(2000);
                    Intent main = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(main);
                    finish(); //kills the current activity
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex){}
            }       
        };
        StartTimer.start();
    }
}
```

Here is the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockwebserver</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

also here are the build path settings:

[image]

Dir structure:
[image]

Comment: Please provide the maven build script that packages the apk.

Comment: Hi Markus, where can i find it?

Comment: Try `.SplashActivity` instead of `com.test.activities.SplashActivity` inside your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: In your project directory where you run the build script eg. `mvn package`, look for a file called `pom.xml` - that is the maven build script that compiles the code and packages the apk.

Comment: .SplashActivity did not work.:\

Added pom.xml to the question above.

Comment: Maybe `.activities.SplashActivity`.

Comment: @MarkusRubey still the same... :(

Comment: What do you have for the package name at the top of the class?

Comment: @codeMagic package com.test.activities;

Comment: please also show your directory structure

Comment: @Zoltán added to the main message.

Comment: So i can see that even when i am changing the package name, it still goes to com.app.test... (as can be seen in the error log)  how can i change it?!  i searched the whole workspace but did not find any results for this.

Answer (score 0):

As I know Maven build systems waiting some pathes, check you project, your sources should be located somewhere like:

/src/main/java/com/test  in your case.

Is your project have such structure?

And also I recommend to name groupid as "com.test"

https://spring.io/guides/gs/maven-android/

Comment: i agree, your top level `com` package should be located in `src/main/java`, not just `src`. Put it there and try again. Maven is very strict with its conventions and it's hard to work around them so it's best not to try to work around them.

Comment: @dilix, So now it the project explorer i see it main.java.com.test.activities. is that the right way? what is the grouping you are referring to?

Comment: @Zoltán So now it the project explorer i see it main.java.com.test.activities. is that the right way?

Comment: So i can see that even when i am changing the package name, it still goes to com.app.test... (as can be seen in the error log) how can i change it?! i searched the whole workspace but did not find any results for this.

Comment: @Gil404 no, your package should still be called `com.test.activities` in the project explorer. You should change your source folder to `src/main/java` instead of just `src` like it is now.